# How to suppress [no test files] message on go test

Tags: testing, go

I'm running `go test ./...` in the root of my project but several packages don't have any tests and report `[no test files]`. If I run `go test ./... | grep -v 'no test files'` I lose the return code from `go test` in case a test fails.

Can I ignore packages with no tests while recursively testing everything from the root of the project?

Comment: What's the problem with [no test files]? I don't think there is any wy to surpress these messages.

Comment: There's no problem, in fact it's a useful message, but I have lots of packages without tests and it clutters the output a little.

Comment: @VitorDeMario Seems like golang wants you to suffer from not having the `_test.go` files :D

Comment: Well, it's been almost a year since I asked. As is the case with most things golang, I now embrace it. `[no test files]` is very useful, I don't suppress it these days.

Comment: I would like to get rid of them. Can be pain hunting though test output for the actual tests. Should be a command line option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo-$$

grep -v 'no test files' </tmp/fifo-$$ & go test ./... >/tmp/fifo-$$
RES=$?
rm /tmp/fifo-$$
exit $RES
```

Comment: That looks good. It's missing a $ on exit $RES, tried to edit but couldn't add only one character.

Comment: @VitorDeMario Sorry, stuff happens.

Answer (score 2):

A relatively compact solution could look like this:

```
set -o pipefail
go test ./... | { grep -v 'no test files'; true; }
# reset pipefail with set +o pipefail if you want to swith it off again
```